# Get inputs from Shiny UI app to the server on Submit or Action button

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I have 15 select (input type) fields. And I need to pass it to the Server function do prediction and show resultant output. **I don't want to auto-update**, when user sets value for one input field, but instead I want user to set values for all (15 input fields) and then press some type of a button to get the output.

how to achieve that? this is my first shiny UI application.

## myCode

```
library(shiny)

dataset <- diamonds
marks <- 0:100
grades <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F")

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
                            h2 {
                            text-align: center;
                            }
                            h3 {
                            text-align: center;
                            }
                            h6 {
                            text-align: center;
                            color:red;
                            }
                            #goButton
                            {
                            width: 100%;
                            }
                            ")
                      )
            ),
  
  verticalLayout
  (
    wellPanel
    (
      titlePanel("Get Recommendation for Year 4 or 5 Courses"),
      h6("* Set the value of input field as 'NA', if you received a remark of Absent (ABS), Medical Circumstances (MC), Exemption (EX), Synoptic Course in absence (NC), Discretionary credits (DC), or any other reason")
    )
    
  ),
   
  fluidRow
  (
    column(2,
           wellPanel(
                radioButtons("type", label = h3("Select Type"),
                choices = list("Grades" = 'grades', "Marks" = 'marks'), 
                selected = 'grades')
                    )
          ),

conditionalPanel
(
  condition = "input.type == 'grades'", 
  
  column
  (2, 
    wellPanel
    (
           h3("Year 1"),
           selectInput('a', 'A',c('NA', grades)),
           selectInput('b', 'B',c('NA', grades)),
           selectInput('c', 'C',c('NA', grades)),
           selectInput('d', 'D',c('NA', grades)),
           selectInput('e', 'E',c('NA', grades))
    )
  ),
  column
  (2,
    wellPanel
    (
           h3("Year 2"),
           selectInput('f', 'F',c('NA', grades)),
           selectInput('g', 'G',c('NA', grades)),
           selectInput('h', 'H',c('NA', grades)),
           selectInput('i', 'I',c('NA', grades)),
           selectInput('j', 'J',c('NA', grades))
    )
  ),
  column
  (2,
    wellPanel
    (
           h3("Year 3"),
           selectInput('k', 'K',c('NA', grades)),
           selectInput('l', 'L',c('NA', grades)),
           selectInput('m', 'M',c('NA', grades)),
           selectInput('n', 'N',c('NA', grades)),
           selectInput('o', 'O',c('NA', grades))
    )
  )
),

conditionalPanel
(
  condition = "input.type == 'marks'", 
  column
  (2, 
   wellPanel
    (
           h3("Year 1"),
           selectInput('a', 'A',c('NA', marks)),
           selectInput('b', 'B',c('NA', marks)),
           selectInput('c', 'C',c('NA', marks)),
           selectInput('d', 'D',c('NA', marks)),
           selectInput('e', 'E',c('NA', marks))
    )
  ),
  
  column
  (2,
   wellPanel
    (
           h3("Year 2"),
           selectInput('f', 'F',c('NA', marks)),
           selectInput('g', 'G',c('NA', marks)),
           selectInput('h', 'H',c('NA', marks)),
           selectInput('i', 'I',c('NA', marks)),
           selectInput('j', 'J',c('NA', marks))
    )
  ),
  
  column
  (2,
   wellPanel
    (
           h3("Year 3"),
           selectInput('k', 'K',c('NA', marks)),
           selectInput('l', 'L',c('NA', marks)),
           selectInput('m', 'M',c('NA', marks)),
           selectInput('n', 'N',c('NA', marks)),
           selectInput('o', 'O',c('NA', marks))
    )
  )
),  
column
(4,
 actionButton("goButton", "Submit"),
 wellPanel
  (
    h3("Results"),    
    verbatimTextOutput("value")
  )
)
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) 
{
  #Do Prediction
  #Get Results
  new_vector = c()

if (input.type == 'marks'){
new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f27sa, 1)
new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f27sb, 2)
new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f27cs, 3)
new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f27is, 4)
new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f27px, 5)

new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f28in, 6)
new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f28da, 7)
new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f28pl, 8)
new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f28sd, 9)
new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f28dm, 10)

new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f28ai, 11)
new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f28fa, 12)
new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f28fb, 13)
new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f28oc, 14)
new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f28pd, 15)
}else{

new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f27sa2, 1)
new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f27sb2, 2)
new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f27cs2, 3)
new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f27is2, 4)
new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f27px2, 5)

new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f28in2, 6)
new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f28da2, 7)
new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f28pl2, 8)
new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f28sd2, 9)
new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f28dm2, 10)

new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f28ai2, 11)
new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f28fa2, 12)
new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f28fb2, 13)
new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f28oc2, 14)
new_vector <- append(new_vector, input$f28pd2, 15)
}
results <- eventReactive(input$goButton,{

return (new_vector)

})
output$value <- renderPrint({ results() })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: snapshot of shiny UI App]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eventReactive` is the way to approach this.

Here is your example modified so that it only returns `"result 1"` if one of the three conditions is true

- the year1 `input$a=="A"`
- the year2 `input$f=="A"`
- the year3 `input$k=="A"`

otherwise it returns `"result 3"`. However note that it doesn't return anything at all until you hit the submit button.

Somehow `eventReactive` is not very well known in the shiny world - but this kind of scenario is exactly what it is meant for. I didn't stumble across it until I had been writing Shiny programs regularly for over a year.

```
library(shiny)

dataset <- diamonds
marks <- 0:100
grades <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F")

ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
                            h2 {
                            text-align: center;
                            }
                            h3 {
                            text-align: center;
                            }
                            h6 {
                            text-align: center;
                            color:red;
                            }
                            #goButton
                            {
                            width: 100%;
                            }
                            ")
  )
  ),

  verticalLayout
  (
    wellPanel
    (
      titlePanel("Get Recommendation for Year 4 or 5 Courses"),
      h6("* Set the value of input field as 'NA', if you received a remark of Absent (ABS), Medical Circumstances (MC), Exemption (EX), Synoptic Course in absence (NC), Discretionary credits (DC), or any other reason")
    )

  ),

  fluidRow
  (
    column(2,
           wellPanel(
             radioButtons("type", label = h3("Select Type"),
                          choices = list("Grades" = 'grades', "Marks" = 'marks'), 
                          selected = 'grades')
           )
    ),

    conditionalPanel
    (
      condition = "input.type == 'grades'", 

      column
      (2, 
        wellPanel
        (
          h3("Year 1"),
          selectInput('a', 'A',c('NA', grades)),
          selectInput('b', 'B',c('NA', grades)),
          selectInput('c', 'C',c('NA', grades)),
          selectInput('d', 'D',c('NA', grades)),
          selectInput('e', 'E',c('NA', grades))
        )
      ),
      column
      (2,
        wellPanel
        (
          h3("Year 2"),
          selectInput('f', 'F',c('NA', grades)),
          selectInput('g', 'G',c('NA', grades)),
          selectInput('h', 'H',c('NA', grades)),
          selectInput('i', 'I',c('NA', grades)),
          selectInput('j', 'J',c('NA', grades))
        )
      ),
      column
      (2,
        wellPanel
        (
          h3("Year 3"),
          selectInput('k', 'K',c('NA', grades)),
          selectInput('l', 'L',c('NA', grades)),
          selectInput('m', 'M',c('NA', grades)),
          selectInput('n', 'N',c('NA', grades)),
          selectInput('o', 'O',c('NA', grades))
        )
      )
    ),

    conditionalPanel
    (
      condition = "input.type == 'marks'", 
      column
      (2, 
        wellPanel
        (
          h3("Year 1"),
          selectInput('a', 'A',c('NA', marks)),
          selectInput('b', 'B',c('NA', marks)),
          selectInput('c', 'C',c('NA', marks)),
          selectInput('d', 'D',c('NA', marks)),
          selectInput('e', 'E',c('NA', marks))
        )
      ),

      column
      (2,
        wellPanel
        (
          h3("Year 2"),
          selectInput('f', 'F',c('NA', marks)),
          selectInput('g', 'G',c('NA', marks)),
          selectInput('h', 'H',c('NA', marks)),
          selectInput('i', 'I',c('NA', marks)),
          selectInput('j', 'J',c('NA', marks))
        )
      ),

      column
      (2,
        wellPanel
        (
          h3("Year 3"),
          selectInput('k', 'K',c('NA', marks)),
          selectInput('l', 'L',c('NA', marks)),
          selectInput('m', 'M',c('NA', marks)),
          selectInput('n', 'N',c('NA', marks)),
          selectInput('o', 'O',c('NA', marks))
        )
      )
    ),  
    column
    (4,
      actionButton("goButton", "Submit"),
      wellPanel
      (
        h3("Results"),    
        verbatimTextOutput("value")
      )
    )
  )
  )

server <- function(input, output) 
{
  #Do Prediction
  results <- eventReactive(input$goButton,{
    if (input$k=="A" | input$f=="A" | input$a=="A" ){
      return("result 1")
    } else {
      return("result 3")
    }

  })
  #Get Results
  #results <- c("result 1","result 2","result 3");
  output$value <- renderPrint({ results() })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, one simple question, before I pull the input values and store it in a vector, I need to find if user selected type as 'Grades' or 'Marks' because then I know whether to use input$f27sa or input$f27sa2. how do I check? I did this: if (input.type == 'marks'){...}else {...} but gives error:  object not found 'input.type'. in short how to check which radio button is selected.

Comment: Let me have a look.

Comment: I think you need to use "input$type". The "." character has no particular significance in R - unlike Javascript for example. It is just another character. The $ is a selector into a list in R, so I think that is what you mean to use.

Comment: you have to use validate need try probably

Comment: Yeah, the `input.type` form is used in the UI part where the conditional is passed to javascript. Thus the "." selector instead of the "$" selector. Interesting. Didn't know how `conditionalPanel` worked until now.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand right your question, I think you should use `isolate` function to achieve this. The idea is easy to understand. You make an `actionButton` and when it's clicked the plot (or another type of output ) is calculated. The point is to isolate the inputs in order to make them no reactive and not change untill you click the button.

Here you have the full explanation: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/isolation.html

I'll put an example with plotOutput:

The idea is to make an action button in the `UI` part of your app just like this `actionButton("goButtoncomparacio", "Make the plot!",width = "200px",icon=icon("play-circle"))`

Then , in the `server` part of your app:

```
output$plotComparacio<-renderPlot({
input$goButtoncomparacio


#You isolate each one of your input. 
#This will make that they dont change untill you click the button. 

embassament<-isolate({input$embcomparacio})
anysfons<-isolate({input$riboncomparacio})
anys1<-isolate({input$datescomparacio1})
anys2<-isolate({input$datescomparacio2})
anys3<-isolate({input$datescomparacio3})
mitjana<-isolate({input$mitjanaComparacio})
fons<-isolate({input$fonscomparacio})
efemeri<-isolate({input$efemeridescomparacio})
previ<-isolate({input$previsionscomparacio})

myplot<-ggplot()+whatever you want to plot
})
```

I hope this helps you. I found it the easiest way to make "Do the plot!" button.